# SQL - IF/ELSE Logic depending on table column

Tags: php, mysql

So, as you may have guessed, I am writing a query to select data from a database. And, as you may have also guessed, I am writing it with the logic of an If/Else statement. Obviously, this isn't as simple in SQL as we all wish it to be. To put the logic into simple terms, here's some sort of pseudo-code version:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on col2 = col1
// Some other JOINS and irrelevant data stuff
if (table2.conditionalColumn == 'x') {
    JOIN table3 ON col3 = col2 WHERE a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
} else {
    JOIN table3 ON col3 = col2 JOIN table4 ON col4 = col3
}
```

I understand that the above query has no resemblance to a proper SQL query in the slightest. What I am trying to find out is how to work around having a column which has a value which determines whether to JOIN to one table, or to join to another table. The whole concept of this is similar to the friend-of-friend system for social networks.

Please feel free to ask for any further explanation of the issue if need be. I have attempted using some `OR`logic, but I got completely stuck. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Edit - To make it easier to understand my goal, I have added a scenario below:

I want to select data from a table named `projects` if the user has a row inside of the `projects_members` table, OR they have a row in the the `teams` table, and that team has a row inside of `projects_members`. There is a column inside of `projects_members` named `memberType`, which is set to 'user' or 'team'.

Comment: I think you can use left join on both target tables and put the conditions inside join conditions. Please say what kind of join (inner,left,full,..) you want to use?

Comment: I was wanting to use an inner and left join to one of the conditional results, and to the other, just a left.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using inner join in one case? What are you trying to achieve? If it's filtering, perhaps it can be done another way.

Comment: I've added a scenario to the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition inside the join conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on col2 = col1
X JOIN table3 t3 ON (col3 = col2 and table2.conditionalColumn = 'x'  
and a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3) 
X JOIN table3 t32 ON (col3 = col2 and table2.conditionalColumn <> 'x')
X JOIN table4 t4 ON (col4 = col3 and table2.conditionalColumn <> 'x')
```

Comment: Using a `JOIN` on a table twice produces the error `Not unique table/alias: 'table3'`

Comment: Your solution provided some good background for building my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I forgot that table3 is repeated twice. So adding alias to table helps to use it twice. Also I don't know what are col3 and col4 etc So you have to update query regarding to the alias names.

Answer (score 1):

So, I fiddled about in my `phpMyAdmin` query builder for a bit, and I found a solution to the issue I had. Here's the solution query in the style of the scenario given to the problem:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users_data t1
INNER JOIN
    teams_members t2 ON t2.memberId = t1.userId
LEFT JOIN
    projects_members p1 ON (
        p1.memberType = 'team' AND p1.memberId = t2.teamId
    )
LEFT JOIN
    projects_members p2 ON (
        p2.memberType = 'user' AND p2.memberType = t1.userId
    )
WHERE
    t1.userName = 'foo'
```